# Why can't I edit the button shape?

Tags: swift, xcode

Hello I am a very new and inexperienced developer and I am trying to border around a button. I'm using the Storyboard and when I used ViewController.swift, I can't make the button a weak var. It is only allowing me to edit the actions. Please help, thank you!

[image]

When I usually do this it allows me to choose if I insert "Action, Outlet or Outlet Collection."

Comment: Try control-dragging down below your viewDidLoad function. Xcode tries to guess which you want to add, and usually gets it wrong.

Comment: If you drag and release, are you able to switch the connection type in the resulting dialog from outlet to action?

Comment: Right-click and drag will also prompt you. By the way, these outlets _do not_ need to be `weak`, it just happens to be the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows "Mates Scene" but your class name is `ViewController`. It also looks like "Mates Scene" has an embed segue to a `ViewController`, so it looks like you might be trying to add an `IBOutlet` to a child view controller from one of the parent view controller's views (the "Home Button").

If so, you can't do that. You may have meant to add "Home Button" to the class of your "Mates" view controller instead.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of iOS Buttons don't have any shape by default. They are displayed as clickable text.

Make sure you are trying to connect your outlet and action from IB to the right target view controller, as suggested by Tyler.

Once you've got the outlet and action links working you can add code to change the appearance.

If you want to make your button a rounded rectangle, say, you can do that with code that manipulates the buttons' layer settings (corner radius, borderWidth, borderColor, and backgroundColor are pretty common properties to edit.)

Here is code that turns a button into a rounded rectangle withe a 1-pixel blue outline and a yellow background color:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let button = button {
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        button.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    }
}
```

### Edit:

That creates a button that looks like this:

[image]

(Note that if you use a border you may need to add some padding so that the border doesn't "crowd" the button title as in my example.)

Answer (score 0):

Drag and release, then from the little menu that appears select `outlet` rather than `action`. Then, to set borders do something like:

```
yourButton.layer.borderWidth = 10
yourButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```